# Woocommerce catalogue page stars

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want in catalogue page to display the stars and in case that there is 0 start or 0 review

No I get the stars only if there is a review

please check the below screenshot

how can i make it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WscTh.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook into [`woocommerce_product_get_rating_html`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_rating_html.html#3404).

Like so:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_rating_html', 'always_get_rating_html' );

/**
 * Always display ratings.
 *
 * @param string $html   The HTML for ratings.
 * @param float $rating  Rating being shown.
 * @param int $count     Total number of ratings.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function always_get_rating_html( $html, $rating, $count ) {
  $label = sprintf( __( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $rating );
  return '<div class="star-rating" role="img" aria-label="' . esc_attr( $label ) . '">' . wc_get_star_rating_html( $rating, $count ) . '</div>';
}
```